# Need assistance with Post/Get Request

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have an issue with the particular website https://damas.terna.it/DMSPCAS08.

I am trying to either scrape the data or to fetch the excel file that it is included.

I tried to fetch the excel file with a post request.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import datetime

url = 'https://damas.terna.it/api/Ntc/GetNtc'

headers = {
    'Host': 'damas.terna.it',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="90", "Google Chrome";v="90"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
    'Referer': 'https://damas.terna.it/DMSPCAS08',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Cookie': '__RequestVerificationToken=5mfiSM2dKte532I8fd3MRdn6nnHbSezkQX29r3fyF2tMegXsvnOInpxy8JvFuDyRVS6pZs03y-NL3CsNsItN1yboc128Kk51yEiuUU0mel41; pers_damas_2019=378972352.20480.0000; rxVisitor=1619766836714T8SRPFLUAH62F1R9K6KG3EKK104BSDFE; dtCookie=7$EC34ED7BFB4A503D379D8D8C69242174|846cd19ce7947380|1; rxvt=1619774462088|1619771198468; dtPC=7$369396404_351h-vIDMPHTCURIGKVKBWVVEWOAMRMKDNWCUH-0e1; DamasNetCookie=F-evmYb7kIS_YTMr2mwuClMB1zazemmhl9vzSXynWeuCII_keDb_jQr4VLSYif9t3juDS6LkOuIXKFfe8pydxSzHPfZzGveNB6xryj2Czp9J1qeWFFT9dYFlRXFWAHuaEIyUQQDJmzWfDBrFCWr309mZoE6hkCKzDtoJgIoor9bed1kQgcdeymAH9lrtrKxwsheaQm2qA-vWWqKjCiruO1VkJ6II_bcrAXU2A_ZPQPznE1_8AEC_AwXmBXETubMQwFAnDXsOLDfEYeQ61TGAupF3d-wz3aZfRs5eCA3kw-en-kpEbS0trwFBQzB-098610GIbIPki9ThVitZ2LN2zza6nn1A8qchqfQC_CZEgu6Jt1glfhHceWS6tvWCuyOEqo2jJpxAajMYXPB6mzlHzX13TiV-jgeFSPehugMAgms_exqocw9w27e4lI5laYZu0rkKkznpZ1mJLOhORwny8-bKa3nRUt7erFv7ul3nLLrgd3FP907tHpTh-qXt1Bmr6OqknDZr_EBN8GY_B2YHV-8hC0AjdqQqpS0xOpp7z_CzzgByTOHSNdeKjVgQfZLQ7amnp71lhxgPeJZvOIl_mIWOr_gWRy_iK6UuzrA3udCTV7bAnUXKB8gX89d9ShQf5tZDxPFchrAQBtdmDChQOA; dtLatC=2; dtSa=true%7CC%7C-1%7CExport%20to%20.xls%7C-%7C1619772685174%7C369396404_351%7Chttps%3A%2F%2Fdamas.terna.it%2FDMSPCAS08%7CTerna%20%5Ep%20NTC%7C1619772662568%7C%7C'

}

parameters = {
    'busDay': "2021-05-01", 
    'busDayTill': "2021-05-01",
    'borderDirId': '1', 
    'borderDirName': "TERNA-APG"
}

response = requests.post(url, data=parameters, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

print(soup.prettify())
```

I am receiving this error:

```
The parameters dictionary contains an invalid entry for parameter 'parameters' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult GetNtc(Damas.Core.Data.DataSource.Data.ParametersModel)' in 'Terna.Web.Controllers.CapacityManagement.NtcController'. The dictionary contains a value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]', but the parameter requires a value of type 'Damas.Core.Data.DataSource.Data.ParametersModel'.
Parameter name: parameters
```

Comment: It looks like you're not calling the API correctly. Is there any documentation available that documents what a valid request looks like?

Comment: @larsks that is my understanding too. Update: I think I found a solution. response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(parameters), headers=headers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't post the answer to your question in the question's body; instead, post it in the answer box:

> `response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(parameters), headers=headers)` seems to solve the issue.